# Calculate fifth and sixth polynomials for Headrick (2002) method for non-normal multivariate distribution

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, skewness, kurtosis, multivariate-distribution

I am trying to perform a 3-variable correlated multivariate Monte Carlo simulation. As the asset class returns are non-normal, I found the following function `rHeadrick` from the package `SimDesign` which utilises the 5th polynomial method to simulate non-normal distributions (Headrick, 2002). However, when running the function `rHeadrick`, I get the following error, even after using 10,000 attempts to obtain the polynomial coefficients. Is there a way to estimate the parameters gam3 and gam4, corresponding to Headrick's 5th and 6th polynomials, separately so that I do not encounter this error? According to the vignette, there are user-specified parameters gam3 and gam4, but the vignette does not provide advice on how to calculate paramters gam3 and gam4

SimDesign vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SimDesign/SimDesign.pdf

```
library(SimDesign)
sim1 <- rHeadrick(5000, mean = muvec, sigma = covmat, skew = skewvec, kurt = kurtvec, control = list(max.ntry = 10000))
Error in headrick02.poly.coeff(skewness[i], kurtosis[i], gam3_fit[i],  : 
  cannot find the coefficients of polynomial after 10000 attempts
```

Comment: What is a non-normal distribution?

Comment: @Xi'an my variables have non-zero skew and excess kurtosis. If it helps, `skewvec = c(-0.6, 0.7, 0.9)` and `kurtvec = c(3.5, 3.2, 2.7)` for skewness and kurtosis respectively. I currently have 3 variables to simulate

Comment: @Xi'an it's ironic that you claim that there is "no way to simulate without making a choice" when I have made a choice to use the Headrick (2002) estimation method for skewed distributions with excess kurtosis. Least you could do is propose some constructive solutions LOL

Comment: "Is there a way to estimate the parameters gam3 and gam4, corresponding to Headrick's 5th and 6th polynomials, separately so that I do not encounter this error? " Unfortunately no, the estimation must be done jointly. It might simply be the case that the gam3 and gam4 coefficients don't uniquely exist given the supplied skewness and kurtosis combinations